# Solr did not come online within 30 seconds version 5.5.0

Tags: solr, solr5

I am trying to start Solr on Windows Server 2012 R2. When I am executing command:

solr start -p 8983 it gives me this error: Solr did not come online within 30 seconds.

The only thing I am getting in logs within file: solr-8983-console is Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap. I have increase it as well.

Still I am not able to Start Solr. Why So? Is there anything else required?

Comment: what was your original heap size and what have you increased it to?

Comment: Thank you for your response. But it is not related with heap size. Next day, when I have started Solr and it works.